# Express a number as an product of $q$ factors such that the maximum factor is minimised.

Tags: number-theory, factoring

We are given as input 2 integers $N$ and $q$. We have to express $N$ as a product of $q$ numbers, such that the maximum number among the $q$ numbers is minimized. The maximum value which $N$ can take is restricted to $10^9$.

Let $N = a_1 * a_2 * \cdots * a_{q-1} * a_q$, where all $a_i$'s are integers. We want the maximum among these $q$ numbers to be minimized.

---

I created a list of prime factorization of $N$. I tried using a greedy approach of taking the $2$ smallest numbers in each step and multiplying and including them in the factors list. But this gave a wrong answer for $N=512$ and $q=3$.

My algorithm returned $16*8*4$ while the correct answer is $8*8*8$. The maximum factor in the former is $16$, while in the latter is $8$.

---

I tried another approach of distributing the prime factors into $q$ boxes, which works for the above case, but fails for $N=12$ and $q=2$. We get the answer as $12=6*2$ instead of the optimal $12=3*4$.

I am stuck and don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find N numbers whose product is equal to a given number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812362/how-to-find-n-numbers-whose-product-is-equal-to-a-given-number)

Comment: As the non-MathJax formatting annoyed me, I chose to fix it for you (and unify on using lowercase q's instead of the mix you had) while thinking about the problem. I'm not really sure this is a maths problem, certainly the bound on $N$ isn't. Perhaps for cs.SE?

Answer (score 1):

Note if $N$ is a $q$-th root, then your problem is minimized by taking $$\underbrace{N^{\frac{1}{q}} \cdots N^{\frac{1}{q}}}_{q-\text{times}}.$$  Otherwise, consider $\lceil N^{\frac{1}{q}} \rceil$, and compute whether $\frac{N}{\lceil N^{\frac{1}{q}} \rceil}$ is an integer.

If not, try $\lceil N^{\frac{1}{q}} \rceil + 1$, and so on.